# Add content to previously blank cell with Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-sheets

I am trying to follow the instructions in the Google API to change contents in a newly created worksheet. I have done the following in the API: Authenticated with OATH2, selected my spreadsheet, and created a new worksheet. However, I cannot figure out how to update the contents of a cell in that worksheet.

I have created the worksheet with these dimensions:

```
        worksheet.Cols = 100;
        worksheet.Rows = 200;
```

However, when using this code to update the cell, it does not work: (based on the code under Change contents of cell [in the API doc here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#work_with_cell-based_feeds))

```
 // Fetch the cell feed of the worksheet.
        CellQuery cellQuery = new CellQuery(worksheet.CellFeedLink);
        CellFeed cellFeed = service.Query(cellQuery);

        Console.WriteLine("Cells:" + cellFeed.Entries.Count);

        // Iterate through each cell, updating its value if necessary.
        foreach (CellEntry cell in cellFeed.Entries)
        {

            if (cell.Title.Text.Equals("A1"))
            {
                cell.InputValue = "test";
                cell.Update();
            }
        }
```

It only works if I have put data into the cell beforehand, but not when created fresh and is thus still blank.

I believe the problem is because the cell feed does not contain any cells in a newly created, blank worksheet. If this is the case, how do I add content to a cell if not by using this method?